# How to give a Confirmation Message on Datatable Page Navigation using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm working on Asp .net MVC3.I'm using html table to display the table in front end.and i'm using datatable plugin for pagination,sorting and filtering.when user selects 2 records on page 1 and navigating to the next page confirmation box has to show as 'do you want to submit the selected values?' if the user clicks ok navigation has to be done otherwise it should remain on page1.Following is my table,

```
<table id="myIndiaTable">
    <thead>
        <th>Select All<input type="checkbox" class="chkheadind" onchange="Getchecked()" /></th>
        @foreach (var item in Model.colName)
        {
            <th>@item.column_name</th>
        } 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.bgv)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkdataind"/></td>
                <td id ="AsscId">@item.AsscID</td>
                <td id ="AsscName">@item.AsscName</td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownList("Education", new SelectList(Model.dd, "Validation_Code", "Validation_Status",  @item.Education),new { style = "width: 80px;" })</td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownList("Employment", new SelectList(Model.dd, "Validation_Code", "Validation_Status", @item.Employment),new { style = "width: 100px;" })</td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownList("Criminal", new SelectList(Model.dd, "Validation_Code", "Validation_Status", @item.Criminal),new { style = "width: 80px;" })</td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownList("DatabaseTest", new SelectList(Model.dd, "Validation_Code", "Validation_Status", @item.DatabaseTest),new { style = "width: 100px;" })</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Following is the jquery,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#myIndiaTable").dataTable({
        "bFilter":true,
        "bSort": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "iDisplayLength": 5,
        "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        "bStateSave": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bDeferRender":true
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used

```
"fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
                 }
```

to reinitialize something whenever the table is drawn again (its not only in the pagination case). This may not suit your case.

For pagination, the documentation suggest to use

```
"fnUpdate": function ( oSettings, fnCallbackDraw )
    {
          // check what you want
          // return true or false. true is expected to paginate and false is expected not to paginate
    }
```